# Plural or single verb to describe each indivisual of similar things

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I wrote:

> The answer to the following questions is a span of the given text.

I mean each answer to each question. Should I write it like:

> The answers of the following questions are spans of the given text?

Answer (score 1):

When there are many questions and each has a separate answer, I think it would be clearer and better to write:

> The answers to the following questions are spans of the given text.

This agreement in number, and makes it clear that there is not a single answer that applies to all of the questions. I tink it would be even clearer to write:

> The answer to each of the following questions is a span of the given text.

This makes it clear that there are many questions, that each question has one answer, and that each answer is one span of text. It also is a smaller change from your original.

By the way, the phrase"span of text" is a little unusual, and I am not sure if it correctly expresses your meaning here, because i am not sure exactly what you intended by it. If you care to explain, here or perhaps better in a separate question, we could advise if there is a different phrase that would express your intended meaning better.

Comment: Text spans pop up in computer-related things sometimes (it defines an unbroken length of text between a given start point and end point) so it could be related to that. But I agree it sounds unusual here.

Comment: Yes as @cactustictacs pointed out, it's some way related to machine reading comprehension in computer science. In such texts the answer is a span of the text that must be extracted. However, if we consider it an instruction to a human user, what else I could say? I want them to highlight a portion of text that is answer to the question.

Comment: Personally, I think if you're dealing with something technical, and that's the usual terminology people would use, you should probably use it too. You could always explain what *span* specifically means before you pose the questions, if necessary! And even if it isn't a term they need to know, it might be helpful to use it, just so you can define exactly what it means in your instructions, so the students know exactly what they need to do. Using another word like *section* or *extract* or *snippet* might be too vague and lead to misunderstandings if you assume they know what you mean.

Comment: @Ahmad I see. I am familiar with the term "span" as used in computer text analysis, and of course in Math, it seemed a bit unusual in this context and i wanted to be sure there was no misunderstanding. You could use "section" or "portion" instead of span, but no major difference. You could say "to answer highlight a section of the given text" or something of the sort.

Comment: If the term "span" is commonly used in this context, by all means use it as @cactustictacs  suggests.